# How do you access url parameters inside of $stateProvider.state's stateConfig object?

Tags: angularjs, authorization, angular-ui-router

```
.state('edit', {
  url: '/edit/:id',
  templateUrl: 'app/skims/form/form.html',
  controller: 'FormCtrl as formCtrl',
  authenticate: {
    loggedIn: true,
    authorized: // :id
  }
})
```

I'd like to assign `authorized` to the `:id` part of the URL. Is there a way to do this?

---

My reason for wanting to do this is so I could set up authorization.

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
  // Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
    if (typeof next.authenticate !== 'undefined') {
      Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
        if (next.authenticate.loggedIn && !loggedIn) {
          alert('Must be logged in to access this route.');
          $location.path('/login');
        }
        if ( next.authenticate.authorized 
          && Auth.getCurrentUser()._id !== next.authenticate.authorized) {
          alert('Unauthorized. Must be signed in as the right user.');
          $location.path('/login');
        }
        if (next.authenticate.admin && !Auth.isAdmin()) {
          alert('Must be an admin to access this route.');
          $location.path('/login');
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Particularly

```
...
if ( next.authenticate.authorized 
  && Auth.getCurrentUser()._id !== next.authenticate.authorized)
```

Comment: The 3rd parameter in the $stateChangeStart event is the next state's params, so you could set `authorized: true` in the state definition and change your check to `if (next.authenticate.authorized && Auth.getCurrentUser()._id !== nextParams.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be solved using the more prams of the `$stateChangeStart` event

```
// instead of this
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {

// we can use this
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart'
       , function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
```

and that means, that we now have access to all passed params inside of the **`toParams`**. We can evaluate that like this:

```
// instead of this
// ...
// && Auth.getCurrentUser()._id !== next.authenticate.authorized.

// we can use 
Auth.getCurrentUser()._id !== toParams.id
```